# non-IIS hosted WCF Services consumed over the internet connecting to back end Database over the internet

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, wcf, sql-server-2008, architecture

I am kind of new to system architecture.  That is, all of my web apps have been relatively flat...two machines at the most running web client and database.

I have been handed the following architecture:

1 VMware machine will run the web application, an MVC 3 app.

1 VMWare machine will host the SQL Server database

1 VMWare machine will host the services.

The machine I'm confused about is the last one.  From what I understand, the services project contains references to three other projects: the model, where the entity framework edmx resides, the entities project, which contains T4 templates that use the entity edmx file as input, and the business project which is where the actual business rules are implemented and the meat of the CRUD actions take place.

From what I understand, the intent is to not run an IIS WCF web services interface, but to make calls to WCF services (like those hosted in the MMC services snap in) on the machine over the internet.  There is a deployment project in the solution for the services project but I don't know if it's configured properly.  I think the idea is to just run the installer on the services machine and it will work.

**My specific question is if there are any important things that I need to keep in mind when implementing, configuring, and deploying these services?**

I'm kind of new to all of this.  I was under the impression that you had to make calls to WCF services via IIS hosted endpoints and that you couldn't (or it at least was inadvisable) to make what amounts to RPC-like calls to machines over the internet.

Comment: Call WCF services over the **internet** without using IIS to host the services? Do you/they realize what that implies? I mean there are some clever hardware implementations that could do this but that doesn't really seem like a good idea.

Answer (score 2):

Since you are new to WCF services, I suggest reading this MSDN article on [Hosting and Consuming WCF services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb332338.aspx).

From what you describe, it looks like you are using `Windows Service` as a host for your WCF service.

The most common choice for a host is `IIS` because of its extensive features including self-starting services, ease of deployment, load balancing and so on.

`Windows Service` is a valid host, provided you can justify the question `'Why not IIS?'`. Maybe, you need full control over the activation and lifetime of your WCF service. Not sure.

p.s. Ensure the account that your Windows Service runs under, has the minimum privileges.